# How to check if key exists in Spark SQL map type

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql, key, exists

So I have a table with one column of map type (the key and value are both strings).

I'd like to write Spark SQL like this to check if given key exists in the map.

```sql
select count(*) from my_table where map_contains_key(map_column, "testKey")
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you could explode your map first, then filter for the desired key, then count

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. Following sql query works

```
select count(*) from my_table where map_column["testKey"] is not null
```

Answer (score 9):

Such construction can be used:

```
df.where($"map_column"("testKey").isNotNull)
```

For pure sql:

```
spark.sql("select * from my_table where mapColumn[\"testKey\"] is not null")
```

Comment: Hi, I know this works, just wonder how to do it with pure spark sql.

Answer (score 1):

The solution will not work if `testKey` is not in the DataFrame schema, this will produce `No such struct field` error.

You must write a small UDF to check, like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

spark.udf.register("struct_get", (root:GenericRowWithSchema, path: String, defaultValue: String) => {

    var fields = path.split("\\.")
    var buffer:Row = root
    val lastItem = fields.last

    fields = fields.dropRight(1)

    fields.foreach( (field:String) => {
        if (buffer != null) {
            if (buffer.schema.fieldNames.contains(field)) {
                buffer = buffer.getStruct(buffer.fieldIndex(field))
            } else {
                buffer = null
            }
        }
    })

    if (buffer == null) {
        defaultValue
    } else {
        buffer.getString(buffer.fieldIndex(lastItem))
    }
})
```

```
SELECT struct_get(mapColumn, "testKey", "") FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 3.0

```
select * FROM table WHERE EXISTS (map_keys(field), x -> x == 'value')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.3+**

SQL:

```sql
map_contains_key(col_name, 'key')
```

PySpark:

```py
F.expr("map_contains_key(col_name, 'key')")
```

Scala:

```scala
expr("map_contains_key(col_name, 'key')")
```